# How to define custom physics body for custom sprites?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Very new to Sprite Kit, trying it out and making a simple game now.

Say I create a .png sprite with both transparent and non-transparent parts (the object is an arbitrary shape) – can I have Sprite-kit automatically figure out the physics body outline so that any non-transparent pixels triggers a collision in my game world, while transparent pixels don't?

Or is the only way to do this is to manually create the shape from CGPathRefs? If so, is there any GUI tool that would help me out with this (I draw an outline, it generates CGPathRefs)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to define the physics body of an arbitrary yourself. If you do not want to do this manually, a good tool is the SKPhysicsBody Path Generator. http://dazchong.com/spritekit/

Comment: PhysicsEditor can do this for you

Comment: Thanks guys, both of these things seem like what I'm looking for!